# If $f$ and $\operatorname{sign}(f)\in L^2([0,1])$, is $f\in L^1([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, solution-verification

Is the following argument correct?

By Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)|\,dy=\left|\int_{[0,1]}f(x)\cdot\operatorname{sign}(f(x))\,dy\right| \le \Vert f\Vert_2\cdot 1\le \infty$$

Does this mean that if $f\in L^2([0,1])$, and $f\not\in L^1([0,1])$, then $\operatorname{sign}(f)$ is not measurable?

Comment: $L^2([0,1])\subseteq L^1([0,1]),$ since $[0,1]$ is a finite measure space. Note that $f$ being measurable implies $f^{-1}([0,\infty))$ and $f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$ are measurable, so $sign(f)$ can be chosen measurable.